# MemTest86 Questions

Tags: usb, uefi, memtest86+

I'm on the Acer Nitro 5 AN515-53, it uses UEFI. I suspect my laptop might have RAM issues and I'd like to resolve them but I've been having trouble using imageUSB.exe to write the image onto a 1GB USB drive. My USB can only support FAT format, and whenever I try to write it gets stuck. I have used **clean all** on my USB, reformatted it and it still gets stuck being written.

**I have a few questions:**

Is there a specific file format that the USB has to be?

What are common errors that cause write progress to be stuck?

When a write is complete/failed can I just use disk part to clean my USB or do I have to use the zero option from the memtest86 software?

Comment: “and whenever I try to write it gets stuck.” - Please explain

Comment: When I write the image onto the USB it has a progress bar, the progress gets stuck at 13.4% and nothing happens. I am forced to remove the USB.

To be honest I think it's just a faulty USB, so I'm asking my friend if I can borrow his for now.

What I'd like to know is if the zero drive option does the same thing as clean from diskpart.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with imageUSB.exe specifically, but writing zeros to flash is a significant difference process than just performing a clean diskpart operation

Comment: In that case do you think clean all will do the same as the zero drive option?

Comment: I literally indicated in my comment that they do significantly different things. Just replace what is very likely due to the software freeze a hardware problem

Comment: Ok, thanks. Sorry I thought clean all completely removes all data on a drive, so I was assuming the zero drive option on MemTest86 did the same. I'm asking this question for when I'm done diagnosing and I want to remove MemTest86 from the USB. If I do the clean option and I don't see any trace of MemTest86 left on can I assume I'm good to go?

Comment: Flash memory works differently than mechanical HDDs, writing data to a flash device, is the only way to permanently get rid of the data, but only the cells the device writes to are actually overwritten.  The clean option on diskpart is primarily to quickly remove the partition.

Comment: So I'm assuming its necessary to use the zero option indicated from the software?